# How (and which tool to use) to send Soap Requests in Azure (Data factory, Logic App, Api Management, ...)

Tags: xml, azure, soap, azure-data-factory, azure-logic-apps

The question is simple, but not so easy to execute in Azure without coming across limitations.
How to ship data from a database to a soap request endpoint?

The flow is as follows: We use a data factory pipeline to fetch weekly data from a database.
What we want to achieve is to send it to an endpoint which is outside the azure domain (so a public ip).
The first flow we had in mind and worked ok, was providing the data in Data factory, send it to a logic app, that logic app uses a custom connector (SOAP). All the activities outputted json (which seems to be the standard) and with the custom connector you could do a Soap-to-rest action, transforming it automatically to a SOAP request.

That was fine until we received the 'hostname' not found errors. We contacted an Azure specialist and he said we needed an integration account, which needs an integration service environment. And that would cost us €4.000 in production. You can image that no customer wants to pay €4.000 per month just to ship 4 times in a month data from one place to another.

[No integration account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgcD7.png)

The error we received was the following

```
{ "error": {
"code": "InternalServerError",
"message": "The remote name could not be resolved: 'molstg-backend.emea.group.atlascopco.com'"}}}
```

Through SOAP and Postman we were able to contact this host. So the issue seemed to be accessing the public endpoint from within the Azure environment.But it did not complain when we entered the hostname into our custom connector for the soap request.

So we tried to reach for solutions, by using Data factory only, since we already have an ISE running there and which is cheaper (serverless, I guess). But Data Factory seems to have its limitations.
There were two pipelines: 1 where the database outputs a soap document (lets call this flow XML), and 1 where it just outputs the records (lets call this flow JSON).

Flow XML doesn't seem to work since it outputs the XML automatically as a JSON-standard, and if I use the xml() function on the output of the lookup activity, it gives a weird result:

```
"body": {
    "$content-type": "application/xml;charset=utf-8",
    "$content": "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(... and a bunch more)"
}
```

Flow JSON seems to do it ok, until I use the xml() function again and it complains it can't handle arrays. I have read the documentation which says that data factory can only work with singleton values, so if you have an array, you'll need to use the foreach. But if we get more then 20.000+ records, i'm not planning to send for each of them a soap request seperatly.

I hear some of you coming: Why don't use Azure Functions? Well our job was this: We want a flow with 0 code, so we don't need to use developers every time we have changes. Which seems reasonable for something simple like shipping data from one place to another, regardless of the format. And with the logic app we were almost there, until the 4K cost showed up.

So any suggestions how to solve this in a not so 4K-a-month expensive way. If the data-factory xml issue could be resolved, then I think we can use that as our http-requester. Otherwise, I'm open for suggestions.

Thanks for reading, I think it is a lot I wrote here, but that's because I tried so many possibilities and I'm close to exhaustion.

Comment: Can you show an error you are getting sending a SOAP request to a public IP?

Comment: Error message has been added, however it is a very vague one, with no more details to be found.